# Create a file in maxscript

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I am trying to gather some data from materials on selections in maxscript and save them to an xml file. At first I was trying with a txt file and I seem to be stuck.

Heres what I have:

```
try(DestroyDialog Test)catch()

Rollout Test "TestMt"  width: 200 height: 120
(
    button btn_name "Connection" height: 50 width:80
    button btn_export "Export Mt Data" height:50 width:90

    fn Createtxt = 
        for o in selection do
                (
                    out_name = ((GetDir #export)+"/testmesh3.txt")
                    out_file = createfile out_name

                )   


            on btn_export pressed do
                (
                    Createtxt()
                )
)

Createdialog Test
```

Comment: What exactly are stuck with? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I am getting an I/O error when running the script, its hit or miss when it saves the file. I could run it once and it saves but i run it for a second time and it fails.

Comment: interesting.......am trying it on a clean max scene and its working fine, (trying it at work maybe its the pipe) so my question is now is, is this the correct line to write to the file?

for o in selection do
   (
     out_name = ((GetDir #export) ="/testmesh.txt)
     out_file = createFile out_name
     format "%,%\n" o.name o.material to:out_file
   )

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you have the Createtxt() function inside the Createtxt function.

try this:

```
try(DestroyDialog Test)catch()

Rollout Test "TestMt"  width: 200 height: 120
(
    button btn_name "Connection" height: 50 width:80
    button btn_export "Export Mt Data" height:50 width:90


                on btn_export pressed do
                (
                    Createtxt()
                )

    fn Createtxt = 
        for o in selection do
                (
                    out_name = ((GetDir #export)+"/testmesh3.txt")
                    out_file = createfile out_name

                )   



)

Createdialog Test
```

Comment: I tried that version and got " Call needs function or class, got: undefined"

isnt it that example the same just with the button on top of the function?
could you explain a bit. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'll attempt to write a piece. Can you tell me what kind of material data you want from the selected object? (assuming you want to save that data into a file)

Comment: thanks a bunch for the help, i was testing to see if i could just get the name of an object and the name of a shader and save it to a text file, upon further finding out some info people say its better to right to an xml since it has instructions and can be used later to read. What do you think? again thanks for the help!

Comment: I have a similar function already finished, will only delete/translate some specific dutch names : ) that are in it.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem nr 1** - Here below you can see a piece code that i wrote, that helps you to assign materials to selected objects. (even based on a external .mat library file) it's fully working.

```
rollout matTests "MatTester_v01" (


global renderwidth = renderWidth
global renderHeight = renderHeight 

    local outputFolderURL = ""
    local bestandsNaam = ""
    local materiaalNaam = #() 
    local saveFolder = "testen" 


    label usage0 "Step 1 - Give your images a filename"     
    edittext filenaam "" fieldWidth:220 labelOnTop:false    
    label usage1 "Step 2 - Choose a save folder"    

    button save_folder "Save folder" width:250
    label usage "Step 3"
    pickbutton kiesGeo "Select your geometry" width:250
    label usage2 "Step 4"
    button btn_loadmat "Open a .mat library" width:250

    on save_folder pressed do 
    (
        outputFolderURL = getSavepath()
        saveFolder = outputFolderURL
    )

    global obj
    --camlist = #()

    on kiesGeo picked obj do
    (
    select obj 
    )

    on filenaam entered txt do
    (

        bestandsNaam = txt
    )   


    on kies_camera selected i do
        format "You selected '%'!\n" scale_dd.items[i]

    on btn_loadmat pressed do 
    (
        local sel = getCurrentSelection()

        if (sel.count == 0) then ( messagebox "no objects are selected" title:"Error 001 - no objects selected" )
        else 
        (
            local libFile = getOpenFileName caption:"select a material library file" types:"Material Libraries (*.mat)|*.mat"
            if (libFile != undefined) then 
            (
                local tempLib = loadTempMaterialLibrary libFile
                if (tempLib == undefined) then ( messagebox "loading a library file failed" title:"Error 002 - loading a library file failed" )
                else 
                (
                    -- save materials in a array

                    for m in tempLib do (
                        global materiaalNaam = #(m) 
                        print materiaalNaam
                    )

                    local aantalmaterials = templib.count 
                    for iterations = 1 to aantalmaterials do -- begin iterations loop
                    (

                        global welkeImage = iterations
                        function snapMats label size:[renderWidth,renderHeight] folder:"testMats" =
                        (
                            for c in cameras do
                            (
                            local fname = folder + label + "-" + c.name 

                            materiaalNaamString = materiaalNaam as string
                            versie = welkeImage as string

                            render camera:c outputFile:(outputFolderURL + "\\" + bestandsNaam + "-" + versie + ".jpg") outputSize:[renderWidth,renderHeight]    

                            )
                        )

                        snapMats "label"

                    local mat = tempLib[welkeImage]

                    sel.material = mat -- assign geindexerd material to my selected geometry
                    meditmaterials[activeMeditSlot] = mat

                    ) -- end for iterations loop


                )
            )
        )
    )
)
createDialog matTests width:250
```

In general - In order to save anything (like material data) to a .txt file, you can for example offer the option for the user to select a folder first.

You do that by crating a simple button in your user interface.
And then do the following:

```
on yourbuttonname_btn pressed do 
(
        inputFolderURL = getSavepath() 
-- this will store the folder URL into the inputFolderURL variable.

)
```

**problem nr 2** - to actually save some data into a .txt file you san do something like:
in the following example, you can see how to store vertes.data into a .txt file (but that can easily also be material data or anything else)

```
tmesh = snapshotAsMesh selection[1]
out_name = ((GetDir #export)+"/testmesh.txt")
out_file = createfile out_name
num_verts = tmesh.numverts
num_faces = tmesh.numfaces
format "%,%\n" num_verts num_faces to:out_file
for v = 1 to num_verts do
(
 vert = getVert tmesh v
 format "%," vert to:out_file
)
format "\n" to:out_file
for f = 1 to num_faces do
(
 face = getFace tmesh f
 format "%," face to:out_file
)
close out_file
delete tmesh
edit out_name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man gonna dissect this and see what i could get! Really appreciated!

Comment: No thanks! you need to do a little bit of cherry picking, but if i'm correct then everything you will need is all there. 

If this is your answer, then please consider marking your question as answered.